# view all certs in a PEM cert file (full cert chain) with openssl or another command

Tags: openssl, x509

often cert files (in PEM) format contain multiple certs like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

with the command:
`openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text` I can see the first entry.

Is there any built-in way to display the second entry or all entries.

Is there any simple way to view all entries?

What I'm really interested in are:
C, ST, O, OU, CN, of subject, the issuer and the subject's validity dates

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The post
[How to view all ssl certificates in a bundle?](https://serverfault.com/questions/590870/how-to-view-all-ssl-certificates-in-a-bundle)
suggests several possibilities:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile CHAINED.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text -noout
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile CHAINED.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout (gives shorter output)
keytool -printcert -v -file <certs.crt>
```

The post contains more variations when using Perl, bash, awk and other utilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I will mark this answer as solution as the crosslink shows multiple solutions.

Comment: for openssl 1.1.1 and higher: a single-command answer can be found here serverfault.com/a/1079893 (openssl storeutl -noout -text -certs bundle.crt)

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest a non-OpenSSL tool: another popular TLS stack, GnuTLS, has a similar `certtool` program which produces output in the same format.

```
certtool -i < multiplecerts.pem
```

(They do differ in some small details, such as decoding of less-common certificate extensions.)

Comment: Indeed this helps.
Will wait a little to see whether there are other answers, but this one will do for my tasks.

I rephrased the title accordingly (replaced "with openssl" with "with openssl or another command"

Comment: I makrjed the other answer as solutions as there are multiple suggestions.

However for my personal usage I will use `certtool`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I found my way here looking to get the subject, validity dates, and issuer from a certificate chain in pem format that contained quite a few commented out lines.

So, on RHEL7 running bash 4.2.46 here's the solution I settled on after extensively reading through the sed documentation over at GNU.org: [sed multiline techniques](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiline-techniques.html#Multiline-techniques)

```
for i in $(sed -n '/^-----BEGIN.*CERTIFICATE-----/{n;p}' CHAIN-FILE-NAME); do
    sed -e '/./{H;$!d}' -e 'x;/'"$i"'/!d' CHAIN-FILE-NAME | openssl x509 -subject -dates -issuer -noout
done
```